# react router: ignore hashchange

Tags: javascript, react-router, dom-events

I have an audio player and I want the current URL always to point to the currently played position. So I thought I'd push a new location to the router with the same key, to tell react router that it should just ignore the hash change.

```
audioElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', (evt) => {
    this.props.router.push({
        ...this.props.location,
        hash: '#'+audioElement.currentTime
    });
});
```

However, as the audio plays back, the page contents keep reloading. How can I prevent the router from reacting to the hashchange event?

I'm using react router 3 and redux. I am willing to upgrade to v4 if it makes the change but it looks too much of an effort just to try.

Answer (score 1):

You are better of putting your `'#'+audioElement.currentTime` in history state , as changing the hash will always cause a refresh (as far as I am aware).

You can do this with something like:

```
audioElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', (evt) => {
    this.props.router.push({
        ...this.props.location,
        state: {
          ...this.props.location.state,
          audioCurrentTime: '#'+audioElement.currentTime
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Purgatory. There is the problem that when I do the push, the URL changes to ```/``` and the page breaks. But it doesn't refresh, so I think we're on the right track. :-)

Comment: @Sixtease I have edited answer, added `...this.props.location`

Comment: I should have seen this earlier: this can't do the job because it won't change the URL in the address bar, so the purpose that copy-pasting the URL would point to the current position can't be accomplished by this... unless I'm wrong. :-)

I also tried applying a router middleware but it doesn't seem possible to cancel a re-render from there, really. :-(

Comment: @Sixtease You need to put the audio time in global state then via something like `redux` instead. Or does it have the `pushState` function?

Answer (score 1):

I got it by patching `react-router/lib/createTransitionManager.js`.
There's a `function listen` where I added roughly this:

```
if (state.location.path === location.path && state.location.hash !== location.hash) {
    /* do nothing */
}
else {
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**: For react-router 4, you need not patch the code, just monkey-patch the router:

```
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
let previousLocation;
const routerSetState = Router.prototype.setState;
Router.prototype.setState = function(...args) {
    const loc = this.props.history.location;
    if (loc.pathname === previousLocation.pathname &&
        loc.search   === previousLocation.search   &&
        loc.hash     !== previousLocation.hash
    ) {
        previousLocation = {...loc};
        return;
    }

    previousLocation = {...loc};
    return routerSetState.apply(this, args);
};
const routerDidMount = Router.prototype.componentDidMount;
Router.prototype.componentDidMount = function(...args) {
    previousLocation = {
        ...this.props.history.location,
    };
    if (typeof routerDidMount === 'function') {
        return routerDidMount.apply(this, args);
    }
};
```